# testing perl after it is installed

Tags: perl

When you build perl from source, you have the option of running `make test` before installing perl in its final destination.

Is it possible to do the equivalent of `make test` after perl has been installed?

Note that I won't have the original source. What I'd like to do is to download the source tar archive for the same version of perl that I have installed and then run the tests (from the source tar archive) against the installed perl.

Possible/impossible? Easy/hard? How would I go about this?

Answer (score 2):

- Possible.
- Hard.
- Not worth it.

Running the tests with the installed Perl instead of the just-built Perl would require you to understand how to persuade the testing system to ignore all the build it hasn't done and get on with running the test using the installed Perl.  You'd not be able to say 'make test' because the first thing it would want to do is build Perl.  Actually, more to the point, you'd not be able to say 'make test' because you wouldn't have a makefile.

Why do you want to do this?  If you don't trust the system Perl, don't use it.  Build your own, test it, and install it in your location instead of a system location.  I do that most of the time; I don't risk breaking the system's Perl by modifying it and use my own.  Of course, I have 5.10.0, 5.10.1, 5.12.1, 5.14.0 and 5.14.1 built (by me) for me to play with.  I usually have at least one 5.8.x version too, but not on this machine at the moment.

Also, remember that the people installing a system Perl are sane.  They run the tests and don't install Perl unless the tests all pass (or substantially all pass).

Comment: That's why I wondering if you have to do a `Configure` and `make` first. Then trick the test harness into using your perl instead of the just built perl.

As for why anyone would want to do this -- suppose you get a tar-ball of an already installed perl. After unpacking it I'd like to be able to test it. I have my reasons :-)

Comment: You'd have to run Configure to get a makefile. If you ran 'make test' without having run 'make' first, then the 'make test' would run the 'plain make' for you, so you would end up with a build of the software before you ran any testing. Further, you would have to work rather hard to avoid testing the modules in the build area and to test the installed modules instead. It is subverting what the Perl test suite was designed for. I suppose you could try copying the installed code over the build, but even that is non-trivial, especially if the layout is not standard.

Comment: I think you'd have to do the inverse of `make install` with your installed Perl. This can be arbitrarily complex or even impossible.

Comment: It seems to me that this is a perfectly reasonable thing to want to be able to do (though perhaps not routinely).  I'm sure the people who create Perl binary distributions have run all the tests themselves, but it's always possible for something to go wrong.  If I'm having problems, I might want to re-test my Perl installation to narrow down the cause.  For example, the distribution itself might be fine, but there might be some problem on my system that causes it to misbehave.  Or an installed file might be corrupted.

Answer (score 2):

Possible, only a little bit hard (no `Configure` or `make` necessary), maybe useful:

The test scheme in the source distribution loads everything out of the directory `/path/to/src/distribution/lib'. The key to running your existing perl installation against this test suite is to put all of the install libraries into this`lib` directory. This can be done with something like:

```
cd /path/to/src/distribution
mv lib lib-original
mkdir lib
/path/to/installed/perl -e 'system qq{cp -prv "$_/." lib/}' \
        -e 'for "lib-original",grep /../,reverse(@INC)'
```

(there's probably a more robust `perl` command that uses `-MFile::Copy`, but this quick-and-dirty one-liner got me going). We use `reverse @INC` so that the libraries from the front of `@INC` will overwrite the later libraries and not the other way around. The `grep /../,...` clause prevents us from copying `.` into `lib`, which would probably not be helpful.

I found a few tests that use hard-coded paths to `perl`, `psed` and `s2p` in the source directory. You'll want to make sure these files exist and that the tests target the installed versions of these programs.

```
rm -f perl t/perl psed t/psed x2p/s2p
ln -s /path/to/installed/perl perl
ln -s /path/to/installed/perl t/perl
ln -s /path/to/installed/psed psed
ln -s /path/to/installed/psed t/psed
ln -s /path/to/installed/s2p x2p/s2p
```

Now use the regular Unix-y idiom for running a Perl test suite:

```
cd t
/path/to/installed/perl -MExtUtils::Command::MM \
        -e 'test_harness(0,"../lib")' */*.t
```

Some tests may be explicitly about testing the integrity of the build-from-source process, so some failures are to be expected.

(this process tested on v5.14.0, v5.8.9, v5.10.1)

**Update:** harder still. There are many other `t` directories inside a typical source distribution. You probably also want to try out:

```
cd /path/to/source/distribution

for dir in */*/
do
        if [ -d $dir/t ] ; then
            pushd $dir
            echo Testing $dir
            /path/to/installed/perl -MExtUtils::Command::MM \
                    -e 'test_harness(0,"../../lib","lib")' t/*.t
            popd
        fi
done
```

Many of these tests are explicitly testing the integrity of the build, so you can expect many of these tests to fail.

Answer (score 1):

You can start by reading the t/TEST file in the perl source code.

Notice the following:

1. It uses "#!./perl" as the she-bang
2. Then at around line 142, it does a chdir to the t directory.

As a start you can modify that she-bang line to point it to your installed perl executable, and copy the content of the 't' directory to the perl core packages directory (or the other way around).

That's how I'd start it.

Another way is to make a list of all installed files when you run make install (make it so that it installs perl in a temporary directory and then do a ls -lR on that directory to ge the list) and then copy those files from the installed perl into your perl source directory.

Use of a version control system (git, for example) can help a lot here so that you can easily roll back to the pristine versions of whatever files that you might have overwritten along the way.

Comment: haven;'t tried this yet, but I suppose I first have to do a `Configure` and a `make`... hmmmm....